# windows wasn't turned off need time to warm up in the morning

Tags: windows-7, performance

Since I have a lot of application need to start and use, I usually don't turned off my PC in office after work.

The problem is that everything I turn on the monitor and login my PC, it takes me a while to warm up these applications. It seems that the windows automatically swaps all the applications to disk, it takes several minutes get them responsive again.

I tried to disable the virtual memeory file, but after that I encountered some errors reporting not enough memory ... I also disabled the power option to sleep, doesn't help.

Any solution, for example can I tell windows not to swap back to disk after office time? (not so environmental friendly)

== Update ==

Tried disable virtual memory again, now it will ask me to close some program when it's short of memory. but I don't have the warm up issue any more.

So I guess it's because at the night other background service like antivirus software make my applications swapped into virtual memory.

In this case my issue is actually not enough memory. (4G RAM not enough .., need to upgrade to win7 64 bits).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your machine hibernates after awhile. You can disable hibernation in the Power Settings - this way the machine will just sleep, and not save its state to disk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell us some details about what type of PC you have. How much memory, processor, what applications you leave open.

Fire up task manager and have a look what swap activity is going on and what memory utilisation is being reported. Assuming that the PC is not going into standby or hibernation, it would be likely that you don't have enough memory installed for the set of applications you want to keep open.

If task manager isn't clear enough, open Resource Monitor as that has more details. Update your question with some additional information so we can give more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis and experiment, I think it's because my setting of file system cache is too big (2 GB). If I set to 1GB, it's much better now.

Here is some guess from my part.

As mentioned in this article ["too much cache"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/11/27/too-much-cache.aspx), it's not good to set file system cache size too big. For example, for my PC several programs are started, after work hour, the other cron program(in my case, the Macfee program) begins to run and drags a lot of file into page cache, since the system doesn't has enough RAM, then the windows kernel will try swap out the inactive program's private memory to get more file cached until it reaches the 2GB limit.

And then, when I　come to office in the next morning and try click those inactive programs, then system has to swap in these memory again (which involves a lot hard drive reading, page cache shrink ?) .... oops.

With memory tools like [RamMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx), this problem can be more easy to be identified.